# Boost: List the vertex and edge attributes specified in GraphML

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I would like to be able to read custom graphml files using the Boost Library's `read_graphml`. This however requires that I specify a-priori the properties/attribute names when reading the file.

Is there a way to instead list the attributes specified in the file or check if a particular attribute exists? I can probably do this by parsing the file but was wondering if it could be done via Boost.

Comment: Do you have a sample GraphML? Or a code snippet that you'd like to change the behaviour of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following starter concept:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08c42b777c7aadbe)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
using namespace boost;

using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge = Graph::edge_descriptor;

struct MyGraph {
    Graph g;
    dynamic_properties dp { [=](auto const&... args) { return detect_properties(dp, args...); } };

    using Name = std::string;
    using EdgePropMap = std::map<Edge, std::string>;
    std::map<Name, std::shared_ptr<EdgePropMap> > _edge_properties;

    void read(std::istream& graphml) {
        ::boost::read_graphml(graphml, g, dp);
    }
  private:
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::dynamic_property_map> detect_properties(dynamic_properties& dp, Name const& name, boost::any const& key, boost::any const& value) {
        auto value_type = core::demangled_name(value.type());

        if (key.type() == typeid(Graph)) {
            std::cout << "Vertex property: " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
            //dp.property(name, boost::make_vector_property_map<Graph>(identity_property_map{}));
            //return dp.lower_bound(name)->second;
        }
        else if (key.type() == typeid(Edge)) {
            std::cout << "Edge property: " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
            if (value.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
                auto& map = *_edge_properties.emplace(name, std::make_shared<EdgePropMap>()).first->second;
                dp.property(name, boost::make_assoc_property_map(map));
                return dp.lower_bound(name)->second;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Value type (" << value_type << ") not supported\n";
            }
        }
        else if (key.type() == typeid(Vertex)) {
            std::cout << "Vertex property: " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
            /*if (value.type() == typeid(std::string))*/ {
                dp.property(name, boost::make_vector_property_map<std::string>(get(vertex_index, g)));
                return dp.lower_bound(name)->second;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Unknown property (" << core::demangled_name(key.type()) << ") " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyGraph g;
    g.read(std::cin);
}
```

For example with the sample input of [this graphml](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nwHyXWJfWQ/) the output is (**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08c42b777c7aadbe)</kbd>**):

```
Vertex property: color, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
Edge property: weight, double
Value type (double) not supported
Edge property: weight, double
Value type (double) not supported
Edge property: weight, double
Value type (double) not supported
Edge property: weight, double
Value type (double) not supported
```

## Improving...

It becomes a little bit more complicated with setting up the edge property maps or when you wish to support disparate value types with them. I'd suggest using `dynamic_properties` as the sole access to the dynamic property maps, because then we can use [shared_ptr to erase the mapped types of `_edge_properties`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#techniques_using_shared_ptrvoid_to_hold_an_arbitrary_object):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba7b21b3c7c432e2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
using namespace boost;

using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge = Graph::edge_descriptor;

struct MyGraph {
    Graph g;
    dynamic_properties dp { [=](auto const&... args) { return detect_properties(args...); } };

    using Name = std::string;
    std::map<Name, std::shared_ptr<void> > _edge_properties;

    void read(std::istream& graphml) {
        ::boost::read_graphml(graphml, g, dp);
    }
  private:
    template<typename Map>
    auto add_property(const std::string& name, Map pmap)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<dynamic_property_map> pm(
                boost::static_pointer_cast<dynamic_property_map>(
                    boost::make_shared<detail::dynamic_property_map_adaptor<Map> >(pmap)));
        dp.insert(name, pm);
        return pm;
    }

    template <typename V>
    auto add_edge_property(std::string const& name) {
        auto map = std::make_shared<std::map<Edge, V> >();
        _edge_properties.emplace(name, map);
        return add_property(name, boost::make_assoc_property_map(*map));
    }

    template <typename V>
    auto add_vertex_property(std::string const& name) {
        // NOTE, if vertex_index isn't present you might want to use
        // make_assoc_property_map as with the edge properties
        return add_property(name, boost::make_vector_property_map<V>(get(vertex_index, g)));
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<dynamic_property_map> detect_properties(Name const& name, boost::any const& key, boost::any const& value) {
        auto value_type = core::demangled_name(value.type());

        if (key.type() == typeid(Graph)) {
            std::cout << "Graph property detected: " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
            //dp.property(name, boost::make_vector_property_map<Graph>(identity_property_map{}));
            //return dp.lower_bound(name)->second;
        }
        else if (key.type() == typeid(Edge)) {
            std::cout << "Edge property detected: " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
            if (value.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
                return add_edge_property<std::string>(name);
            } else if (value.type() == typeid(double)) {
                return add_edge_property<double>(name);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Value type (" << value_type << ") not supported\n";
            }
        }
        else if (key.type() == typeid(Vertex)) {
            std::cout << "Vertex property detected: " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
            if (value.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
                return add_vertex_property<std::string>(name);
            } else if (value.type() == typeid(double)) {
                return add_vertex_property<double>(name);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Value type (" << value_type << ") not supported\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Unknown property (" << core::demangled_name(key.type()) << ") " << name << ", " << value_type << "\n" << std::flush;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyGraph g;
    g.read(std::cin);
}
```

Now prints:

```
Vertex property detected: color, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
Edge property detected: weight, double
```

## Notes:

The second version is actually a lot safer in that the first one "mis-used" `lower_bound` to find the property that was just added by name. This could *break* badly if there were Edge/Vertex properties *by the same name*.

The second version adds a helper function that avoids that inaccuracy (`add_property`).

Comment: If you just wanted to "detect" (not consume) the properties, then obviously the code is much simpler.